# How to use bimap on [Either] idiomatically? Maybe something else to map element of [Either] using two functions

Tags: haskell

How to apply two functions over list of `Either a b` in more idiomatic way (I guess it may be applying `bimap` correctly)? (without using `instance ... where` as I would like flexibility on "one off" applications of different `f g` functions -> `biEitherTransformGenerator` and `biEitherFmap` allow one-liners)

I try to use `bimap` to map two functions over list of `Either a b`:

```
biEitherTransformGenerator :: (a->c) -> (b->d) -> Either a b -> Either c d
biEitherTransformGenerator f g (Left x) = Left $ f x
biEitherTransformGenerator f g (Right x) = Right $ g x
biEitherFmap :: (Functor container) => (a->c) -> (b->d) -> container (Either a b) -> container (Either c d)
biEitherFmap f g = fmap $ biEitherTransformGenerator f g
el = [Left 5, Right "foo", Left 10, Right "bar"]:: [Either Int [Char]]
main = do
    print el
    let l1 = fmap (biEitherTransformGenerator (*2) (++"!!!")) el
    print l1
    let l2 = biEitherFmap (*2) (++"!!!") el
    print l2
    print $ l1 == l2
    -- let l3 = fmap (bimap (*2) (++"!!!")) el
    -- print l3
```

Output of `runhaskell DoubleFunctor.hs` :

```
[Left 5,Right "foo",Left 10,Right "bar"]
[Left 10,Right "foo!!!",Left 20,Right "bar!!!"]
[Left 10,Right "foo!!!",Left 20,Right "bar!!!"]
True
```

every time I uncomment last two lines:

```
let l3 = fmap (bimap (*2) (++"!!!")) el
print l3
```

I get:

```
DoubleFunctor.hs:14:20: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      bimap
        :: (Integer -> Integer)
           -> ([Char] -> [Char]) -> Either Int [Char] -> b
   |
14 |     let l3 = fmap (bimap (*2) (++"!!!")) el
   |                    ^^^^^
```

What I try to achieve: More idomatic way of doing `fmap (biEitherTransformGenerator f g) listOfEither` or `biEitherFmap f g listOfEither`.

Comment: You need to import [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) first, which comes from the `bifunctors` library (which you may need to install first; I don't recall if that's one of the standard libraries).

Comment: @chepner Data.Bifunctor is in base now, no need to install anything unless you have an old ghc.

Comment: Thanks for comments! There was something screwed up with my install. You motivated me to reinstall things and finally import works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Bifunctor` class is not part of the Prelude; you need to import it from `Data.Bifunctor` first. (Depending on your installation, the module may be provided by the `base` library, or you may need to install the `bifunctors` library first.)

```
Prelude> :t bimap

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: bimap
Prelude> import Data.Bifunctor
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> :t bimap
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> el = [Left 5, Right "foo", Left 10, Right "bar"]
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> fmap (bimap (*2) (++"!!!")) el
[Left 10,Right "foo!!!",Left 20,Right "bar!!!"]
```

Comment: I had some trouble with my installation and strange errors when I tried to import. So I thought that it may be not thing of importing. Thanks to your answer, I reinstalled things to make sure, and importing finally works! Thanks!